# Profile heap allocations during a period of time

Tags: go, profiling, heap-memory

I'm trying to profile a server that I'm running. I'm mostly following https://artem.krylysov.com/blog/2017/03/13/profiling-and-optimizing-go-web-applications/

I add the following code to allow profiling:

```
    mux.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/", pprof.Index)
    mux.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/cmdline", pprof.Cmdline)
    mux.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/profile", pprof.Profile)
    mux.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/symbol", pprof.Symbol)
    mux.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/trace", pprof.Trace)
```

I start some benchmarks and I run `go tool pprof http:/.1:8080/debug/pprof/profile?seconds=5`, this works as expected since it profiles the cpu during 5 seconds.

I would like to do the same with the heap. However, if I do `go tool pprof -alloc_objects http:/.1:8080/debug/pprof/profile?seconds=5` I get all allocations, not just the allocations during the last five seconds.

In my particular case I'm running a lot of allocations at boot time and they mask all the others. Is it possible to restrict them to this period? If I execute trace I can see that the heap is incrementing, but I cannot query what objects are there.

I've tried to take two different snapshots of the heap and use go tool pprof with --base. However it does not work, it shows 0 differences. My guess is that objects are too small compared with the total memory allocated so they are not saved to the profile.

Comment: try starting the trace manually using `runtime.StartTrace`. Not sure it will work but if it does do report back and make it an answer.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer could you elaborate a bit more. How could runtime.StartTrace prevent the recording of the previous heap? I suppose that is started inside net/http/pprof

Comment: I mean do not run the program with any special flags, and control profiling from within your code. That way you decide when things are sampled.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer that is exactly what the net/http/pprof endpoints do, isn't it?